# Why isn't this web site substitution rule not working?

Tags: lotus-domino

I have an agent that sends out a url to a file.  In order to hide the specifics of where that file exists, so I thought I'd create a Web Site substitution rule.  So instead of the full url to this file, I decided to send out the following url in an email:

https://< website >/Terms/n=< file name >

I created a Web Site Rule that would map this url to the full url containing the location of the file.  The rule is as follows:

RULE: Substitution

INCOMING URL: /Terms/n=*

REPLACEMENT: /db.nsf/< view unid >/< document unid >/$FILE/*

I'm getting a 404,  File not found or unable to read file.  The full url is good -- I know that because I displayed in the agent log and checked it.  Any ideas why this is not working?

thanks
Clem

Comment: Does the actual direct URL work (https://< website >/db.nsf/< view unid >/< document unid >/$FILE/filename)?

Comment: yep... I made sure by dumping it into the agent log and checking it.

Comment: Are there any other internet site rules for <website>?

Comment: yeah, there are a bunch of them.

Comment: Any reader fields associated with the view or document?

Comment: Try this incoming url instead: /Terms/* (and then test with /terms/filename)

Comment: I just tested a similar substitution rule on my server and /test/n=* works just fine. So it must be one of the other internet site rules for your website that conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Per for trying it out and determining that it SHOULD work.  I looked at everything in detail and found that in my Rule had a typo.   I actually had double-quotes instead of an asterisk!  So I had  /Terms/n=" instead of /Terms/n=*.  Can't believe I missed that.

Thanks!

clem

Comment: I’m glad you found the reason 